# QTextDocument HTML Table width

Tags: html, qt, qtextdocument

I'm struggling with a QT5 problem. I'm trying to build (and then paint on a `QPainter` object) an HTML table. This is my code:

```
QTextDocument td;
QString table_style= QString("<style type=\"text/css\">"
                             ".tg  { table-layout: fixed; width: 200px; }"
                             ".tg td{padding-bottom: 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;}"
                             ".tg .tg-3x1q{color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); text-align:right}"
                             ".tg .tg-6bqv{color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); padding-left: 5px;}"
                             "</style>");

QString table_html = QString(" <table width=\"500px\" class=\"tg\">"
                             "<tr>"
                               "<td class=\"tg-3x1q\" width=\"150px\">1</td>"
                               "<td class=\"tg-6bqv\" width=\"150px\"><sup>th</sup></td>"
                             "</tr>"
                             "<tr>"
                               "<td class=\"tg-3x1q\" width=\"150px\">2</td>"
                               "<td class=\"tg-6bqv\" width=\"150px\"><sup>rpm</sup></td>"
                             "</tr>"
                             "<tr>"
                               "<td class=\"tg-3x1q\" width=\"150px\">3</td>"                   
                               "<td class=\"tg-6bqv\" width=\"150px\"><sup>km/h</sup></td>"
                             "</tr>"
                             "</table>");

td.setDefaultStyleSheet(table_style);
td.setHtml(table_html);
td.drawContents(painter);
```

The table is correctly showed in the painter BUT has no fixed column width. To achieve that result I've tried almost everything:

- Setting `table-layout: fixed` but from [QT's docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)  is not supported (but width is!)
- Setting the `width` with or without double quotes, relative or absolutely
- Inserting in each cell a `div` with a fixed width
- Tried (following this question http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31661-QTextDocument-style-CSS-does-not-work) to add the style with the body. Like this

  ```
  td.setHtml(table_style + table_html);
  ```

None of these ways worked. Moreover, if I try to add some spaces to pad the row they were trimmed out once the table was painted. I've also read that I could use the `WebView` to achieve the result but it's too slow.
I'm stuck, I hope that someone could help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QTextDocument` is not a renderer of any standard HTML. It implements a slightly incompatible HTML- and CSS-subset. For example, the `px` suffix is not supported. All dimensions are either in pixels (without a suffix) or in percent (with `%` suffix). You might wish to try the widths without the `px` suffix.

You can only rely on `QTextDocument`-related documentation of the markup it implements, not on general HTML/CSS documentation.